# Delete using ajax with a ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the below that doesn't seem to work. Where am i going wrong.
The requesting data works fine but when I want to delete using the id from the retrieved data it doesn't do anything.

**date.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/
    ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document)
        .ready(function () {
            $(".date,.site")
                .change(function () {
                    var site = $("#site")
                        .val();
                    var id = $("#date")
                        .val();
                    var dataString = 'id=' + id + '&site=' + site;

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST"
                        , url: "process.php?process=dselect"
                        , data: dataString
                        , cache: false
                        , success: function (html) {
                            $(".data")
                                .html(html);
                        }
                    });

                });

        });
    $(document)
        .ready(function () {
            $(document)
                .click('.delete', function () {
                    var id = $("#data")
                        .val();
                    var dataString = 'id=' + id;
                    alert(dataString);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST'
                        , url: 'process.php?process=delete'
                        , data: dataString
                        , success: function (data) {
                            if (data == "YES") {
                                alert("Holiday Deleted")
                            } else {
                                alert("can't delete the row")
                            }
                        }

                    });
                });

        });

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="get" action="index.php">
        <select name="site" class="site" id="site">
                    <option>Select Site</option>
                    <option value="Self Park North">Self Park North</option>
                    <option value="Self Park South">Self Park South</option>
                    <option value="Valet North">Valet North</option>
                    <option value="Valet South">Valet South</option>
                    <option value="Summer Special">Summer Special</option>
                    <option value="cleaners">Cleaners</option>
                                </select>
        <br />
        <input name="date" type="date" value="" id="date" class="date" />
        <p>Select Patroller</p>
        <select name="data" class="data" id="data" size="20" style="width:400px;">

                        </select>
        <br />
        <input name="delete" type="button" value="delete" class="delete" id="delete" />
        <input name="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />

    </form>
```

**process.php**

```
case "delete":
 include('dbconnect.php');
 if ($_POST['id']) {
     $id = $_POST['id'];
     $query = "DELETE FROM taken WHERE id = '$id'";
     if ($conn - > query($sql) === TRUE) {
         echo "Record deleted successfully";
     } else {
         echo "Error deleting record: ".$conn - > error;
     }
 }
 break;
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you tell us what errors you're getting? Specifically, are you getting something like `Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '>'`? If so, you could try changing `$conn - > query` to `$conn->query` ...

Comment: you may need to recheck what your returning from server side script to ajax call,  because  this `if (data == "YES") {` looks like meaningless since your returning some other string literal from server side script

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell without complete information - error messages, the definition of the variables you're showing us in the PHP snippet etc. You should check your error logs to see what's actually going on.

That said, there's an error around this:

```
if ($conn - > query($sql) === TRUE) {
```

If you try running something simple in PHP to test whether you can expand operators that way you'll see something like the following:

```
$ php -a
Interactive mode enabled

php > $a = (object) array("1" => "one", "two" => 2);

php > echo $a->two . PHP_EOL;
2

php > echo $a -> two . PHP_EOL;
2

php > echo $a - > two;
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '>' in php shell code on line 1
```

You can see that surrounding the operator by whitespace is OK, but splitting it up isn't.

This would cause your script to break, but because you haven't included the errors you're seeing I can't be sure it's the only problem.

Comment: the code wasn't split up, some jobs worth has edited the post and messed with original code i submitted. but thank you for the enlightenment much appreciated.